# Why some claims are shown in grey while others in black?

Tags: us7904356

In US 7904356 patent claims 1& 8  are in black, others in grey. Is there any meaning of the   difference?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at google's enhanced, value added view of the patent, not the patent as issued. They highlight the independent claims for readability. Click download PDF to see the actual patent.